# Cannot find module 'application-settings'

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I'am getting an error when trying to include "application-settings module".

*Cannot find module 'application-settings'  <----- Error

the error is in my storage.driver.ts which is in nativescript sdk which is built using loopback sdk builder

storage.driver.ts

```
import * as AppSettings from 'application-settings'; <---- Error here
export class StorageDriver {
static set(key: string, value: any) {
AppSettings.setString(key, String(value));
}
static get(key: string): any {
return AppSettings.getString(key);
}
static remove(key: string): any {
if (AppSettings.hasKey(key)) {
  AppSettings.remove(key);
} else {
  console.log('Trying to remove unexisting key: ', key);
}
}
}
```

- https://github.com/m-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder/wikiean

what should i do to resolve this issue? I am new to nativescript.

Comment: The repo isn't accessible, is it private?

Comment: node-modules -> tns-core-modules -> application-settings

Comment: I was referring to the one linked to in the original post, before the code snippet

Answer (score 13):

*'application-settings'* was moved to *'tns-core-modules'*, which is now deprecated as *'application-settings'* and other core nativescript modules are now a part of *'@nativescript/core'*.
Now we use ***'@nativescript/core'*** instead of *'tns-core-modules'*.

*@deprecated*

```
import * as AppSettings from 'tns-core-modules/application-settings';
```

Use this instead :

```
import * as AppSettings from '@nativescript/core/application-settings';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would import it

```
const applicationSettings = require('tns-core-modules/application-settings')

// or if you are using webpack for example
import * as applicationSettings from 'tns-core-modules/application-settings'
```